# Get a list of all installed applications on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, integration

Is it possible to get a list of all applications installed in a Blackberry, similar to the applications list when you go into your settings.

I can get a list of all visible applications using the following but I was wondering if it's possible to get a list of apps that aren't necessarily running but are installed,

```
ApplicationDescriptor[] descriptors = 
    ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().getVisibleApplications();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
net.rim.device.api.system.CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandles()
```

To get an array of handles into all modules, and:

```
net.rim.device.api.system.CodeModuleManager
    .getApplicationDescriptors(int moduleHandle)
```

To get ApplicationDescriptors associated with the module. You will have to sort out which modules are libraries and which are applications.

Comment: Hello, I can't get application name. please Define how can i use this function?

Comment: You get the name from the array of ApplicationDescriptors returned by getApplicationDescriptors().

Comment: Thanks for your replay, if you have example of this so please add. Because i try to more time but throw null pointer exception in my code.

Comment: Hello, How to sort out which module are libraries or which are application?